# Including php files in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a plugin that makes a custom content type and enables that custom content type to display its own archive pages. That is, this custom content type will display with archive-customtype.php rather than archive.php.

I don't want this, however. I want archive content to display in the same way whether it's a post or a new content type.

I can't just remove archive-customtype.php because the plugin expects it to be there. Can I remove everything from that file and simply say:

```
    <?php include("archive.php"); ?>
```

That works but I want to make sure this is the best wordpress way to do it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [`locate_template`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template) or [`get_template_part`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) rather than `include`. You should be able to do `get_template_part( 'archive' );`-- note that there is not file-type ending.

It worries me that it doesn't work if you just remove `archive-customtype.php`. As you realize, `archive.php` should just work. It should be the fallback template. That the plugin requires this file is odd and makes me worry that something will break, or is broken and you haven't noticed.

Comment: Good call. The truth is that I'm the one making the plugin based on a tutorial on wp.tutsplus. There's code in there that tells the plugin to use a special template (add_filter('template_include', 'include_template_func', 1); That function tells wordpress to use a special archive template if it's present (which I want) and if it isn't to use a backup template in the plugin directory (which I don't want). So I removed that part and it works well without needing to include anything.